# WPF DataGrid: How to perform column binding using code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

This is the column in question:

```
<DataGridTextColumn
    Header=" Length "
    Width="Auto"
    Binding="{Binding Path=Length, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=0.00;;#}"
    ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightJustified}"
    x:Name="lengthColumn">
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The problem is that I need to bind that column to some other property (called `Length48`) at run time.

TIA.

Comment: Please clearify You want to change Binding from Length to Length48 or this binding is not working at all.

Comment: Here is your answer, taken from my post: `The problem is that I need to bind that column to some **other** property (called Length48) at run time.` The posted binding is used in a `TabItem` and the new one in another `TabItem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataGridTextColumn dataGridTextColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
dataGridTextColumn.Header = " Length ";
dataGridTextColumn.Binding = new Binding("Length48");

YourDataGrid.Columns.Add(dataGridTextColumn);
```